# Cannot redirect the response to my controller after publishing the project in azure : AuthBot

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, botframework, redirect

I'm trying to create a bot in which the user has to first log in with his microsoft account, for that i created an app in Azure Active Directory that returns to my controller the access tokens (redirect URL). So, a fixed the redirect URL to my controller in this app as :

```
http://localhost:3984/api/OAuthCallback
```

And it works just fine locally, i get locally the response from the AAD App to my controller. However after publishing my project in azure this doesn't work because the project is no longer in localhost and the redirection response to my controller does no longer work.

Can someone help me please ? WHat redirect URL can i add to my AAD app in order to redirect the response to my controller in Azure ?

This is the AuthBot that i'm talking about :

https://github.com/Ellerbach/SharePointBot/tree/master/AuthBot

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add another redirect URL in the AAD App that redirect to your azure controller, in my case it's something like this :

https://*****.azurewebsites.net/api/OAuthCallback

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please consider using [Botauth](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth) and not [Authbot](https://github.com/Ellerbach/SharePointBot/tree/master/AuthBot) as the Authbot project has been discontinued and is not updated to the latest bot framework changes.
[image: Authbot discontinued]

Secondly, as you said, add your bot (hosted in Azure) url followed by `/Callback` i.e `https://*****.azurewebsites.net/Callback` to the redirect url of your Azure Active Directory app when you use AuthBot.